# Unboxed Vectors for simple data types

Tags: haskell, vector, unboxing

I want to use unboxed vectors on a simple newtype, but it's not clear to me how to enable this. What I have so far:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

module UnboxedTest where

import Data.Vector.Unboxed
import Data.Word

newtype X = X Word64 deriving (Unbox)
```

I get:

```
src/UnboxedTest.hs:11:32: error:
    • No instance for (Data.Vector.Generic.Base.Vector Vector X)
        arising from the 'deriving' clause of a data type declaration
      Possible fix:
        use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration,
          so you can specify the instance context yourself
    • When deriving the instance for (Unbox X)
   |
11 | newtype X = X Word64 deriving (Unbox)
```

How do I enable this to be put inside an unboxed vector?

Comment: You can use unboxed tuples: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.12.1/docs/html/users_guide/primitives.html#unboxed-tuples

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty simple if there is an isomorphic type that can already be stored inside unboxed vectors. For `Point` that is `(Word64, Word64)`.

You have to do as that documentation page says and write:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
import Data.Vector.Unboxed
import Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable (MVector)
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic as G
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable as GM
import Data.Word

data Point = Point Word64 Word64

newtype instance MVector s Point = MV_Point (MVector s (Word64,Word64))
newtype instance Vector    Point = V_Point  (Vector    (Word64,Word64))

instance GM.MVector MVector Point where
  {-# INLINE basicLength #-}
  basicLength (MV_Point v) = GM.basicLength v
  {-# INLINE basicUnsafeWrite #-}
  basicUnsafeWrite (MV_Point v) i (Point x y) = GM.basicUnsafeWrite v i (x, y)
  ...

instance G.Vector Vector Point where
  {-# INLINE basicLength #-}
  basicLength (V_Point v) = G.basicLength v
  {-# INLINE basicUnsafeIndexM #-}
  basicUnsafeIndexM (V_Point v) i = do
    (x, y) <- G.basicUnsafeIndexM v i
    pure (Point x y)
  ...

instance Unbox Point
```

These declarations specify how your `Point` can be converted to a `(Word64, Word64)` to be stored in the unboxed vector. It becomes slightly more obvious that these are not completely redundant if you look at for example the `basicUnsafeWrite` and `basicUnsafeIndexM` function where you can see that you actually do need to write some code to convert `Point` to `(Word64, Word64)` and back.

Comment: Actually, doesn't appear to work after all.

Comment: @Ana you're right, I thought it would work, but it doesn't. I've removed that part of my answer.

Comment: Very scary code! I think instead of this I will go back to already-supported unboxed vectors and wrap/unwrap as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Since version `vector-0.13` it is possible to use `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` to derive `Unbox`, see [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.13.0.0/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html#description)

Here is the example from haddock:

```hs
>>> :set -XTypeFamilies -XStandaloneDeriving -XMultiParamTypeClasses -XGeneralizedNewtypeDeriving
>>>
>>> import qualified Data.Vector.Generic         as VG
>>> import qualified Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable as VGM
>>> import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed         as VU
>>>
>>> newtype Foo = Foo Int
>>>
>>> newtype instance VU.MVector s Foo = MV_Int (VU.MVector s Int)
>>> newtype instance VU.Vector    Foo = V_Int  (VU.Vector    Int)
>>> deriving instance VGM.MVector VU.MVector Foo
>>> deriving instance VG.Vector   VU.Vector  Foo
>>> instance VU.Unbox Foo
```

Comment: I tried that with the latest GHC. `deriving instance M.MVector MVector Foo` errors. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Ana You are right. I totally forgot that this example was recently fixed on master, but haven't been released yet: https://github.com/haskell/vector/pull/450
Fixed the answer

Answer (score 1):

Although Haskell's various deriving mechanisms are still not able to generate instances of classes pertaining to a type family (like [`Unboxed.Vector`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.13.0.0/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html#t:Vector) in this case), there's always the possibility to generate instances with Template Haskell, which can do basically anything you can do by hand. And fortunately, somebody has already written macros that generate `Unbox` instances, in the [`vector-th-unbox` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-th-unbox-0.2.2/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed-Deriving.html):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, MultiParamTypeClasses, TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances #-}

import Data.Vector.Unboxed.Deriving (derivingUnbox)

newtype X = X Word64

derivingUnbox "X"
   [t| X -> Word64 |]
   [| \(X w) -> w |]
   [| X |]
```

Actually, since this is a newtype I'm tempted to suggest a macro that's even simpler to use:

```
import Data.Coerce
import Language.Haskell.TH

derivingNewtypeUnbox :: String -> TypeQ -> DecsQ
derivingNewtypeUnbox tfq tg = derivingUnbox tfq tg [|coerce|] [|coerce|]
```

And then it's just

```
derivingNewtypeUnbox "X" [t| X -> Word64 |]
```